How to create a list that contains 25000 (18*18) matrix efficiently?
Im trying to make a list that contains 25000 (18*18) tight-binding Hamiltonian matrix for 25000 kpoints which is a function of (kx,ky,kz) when i do so it takes about 34seconds i want a way that is more efficient because I will need to create a list that has a 1000000kpoints
onsitematrix1 = 
  Table[If[i == 1 && j == 1, Subscript[\[Epsilon], s], 
    If[1 < i <= 4 && 1 < j <= 4 && i == j, Subscript[\[Epsilon], p], 
     If[i == j && 4 < j <= 9 && 4 < i <= 9, Subscript[\[Epsilon], de],
       If[i == 10 && j == 10, Subscript[\[Epsilon], s], 
       If[i == j && 10 < i <= 13 && 10 < j <= 13, 
        Subscript[\[Epsilon], p], 
        If[i == j && 13 < i <= 18 && 13 < j <= 18, 
         Subscript[\[Epsilon], de], 0]]]]]], {i, 18}, {j, 18}];
notonsitematrix1 = 
  Table[hammatn[Subscript[v, ss\[Sigma]], Subscript[v, sd\[Sigma]], 
    Subscript[v, dd\[Sigma]], Subscript[v, dd\[Pi]], Subscript[v, 
    dd\[Delta]], Subscript[v, sp\[Sigma]], Subscript[v, pp\[Sigma]], 
    Subscript[v, pp\[Pi]], Subscript[v, pd\[Sigma]], Subscript[v, 
    pd\[Pi]], near[[i]], {kx, ky, kz}], {i, 1, 8, 1}];
exchmat = 
  Table[If[i == j && i <= 9 && j <= 9, -1/2 ii M Cos[\[Theta]], 
    If[j == i + 9 && i <= 9 && 9 < j <= 18, -1/
      2 M ii Sin[\[Theta]] Exp[-I \[Phi]], 
     If[i == j + 9 && 9 < i <= 18 && j <= 9, -1/
       2 M ii Sin[\[Theta]] Exp[I \[Phi]], 
      If[i == j && i > 9 && j > 9, 1/2 M ii Cos[\[Theta]], 0]]]], {i, 
    18}, {j, 18}];
ham1 = onsitematrix1 + Sum[notonsitematrix1[[i]], {i, 1, 8, 1}] + 
   exchmat + 0.06 lmattot;

k1 = ToPackedArray[kptsm[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, (2 \[Pi])/a}, 5000], 
   Complex];
k2 = ToPackedArray[
   kptsm[{0, 0, (2 \[Pi])/a}, {0, \[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a}, 5000], Complex];
k3 = ToPackedArray[kptsm[{0, \[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a}, {0, 0, 0}, 5000], 
   Complex];
k4 = ToPackedArray[
   kptsm[{0, 0, 0}, {\[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a}, 5000], Complex];
k5 = ToPackedArray[
   kptsm[{\[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a}, {0, 0, (2 \[Pi])/a}, 5000], 
   Complex];
kptstot = ToPackedArray[Flatten[{k1, k2, k3, k4, k5}, 1], Complex];
{kxlist, kylist, kzlist} = Transpose[kptstot];
f = ToPackedArray[
  Compile[{{kx, _Real}, {ky, _Real}, {kz, _Real}}, ham2[kx, ky, kz]]]
ToPackedArray[
  Table[N[cf[kxlist[[i]], kylist[[i]], kzlist[[i]]]], {i, 1, 25000}], 
  Complex];


I used AbsoluteTiming on your onsitematrix1 and got 0.0015 seconds, SparseMatrix for the same and got 0.00009 seconds, Normal[SparseMatrix and got 0.0002 seconds. So that looks like you might possibly get a 7.5x increase in speed of construction. Please try that on your all your code and see if you get this same increase.

I'm sorry. That should have been SparseArray, not SparseMatrix  I was concentrating on building your matrix and inserted the wrong word into my comment.

Your code throws several errors due to missing definitions. In you own interest, you should post the missing code; otherwise people will be less inclined to help you here.
